# apply flat edges to accordion only

Tags: css

I found this code where it can turn the cornes flat. It works well and all, but it turns everything straight. How do i just limit this to the accordion only. Ive try giving it an ID and applying to just that but it stops working when i do that. Can someone tell me the correct way. Thanks in advance!

```css
 * {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of web pages. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify the target elements. For example:

```
 #accordion, #accordion * {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
 }
```

The above code will apply the css rule to the accordion and all of it's children.

On a slightly different note, I'm not sure exactly why you're using `!important` in this instance.